# How to negate a boolean expression when using the elvis operator in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to negate the following expression:

`return SpUtils.loadEMail()?.isEmpty() ?: false`

If i add a ! before the expression, like

`return !SpUtils.loadEMail()?.isEmpty() ?: false`

The IDE(Android Studio) tells me

> Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type kotlin.Boolean?

How do I negate this kinds of expressions?

Comment: As a side note, there is also the `.not()` function which you can use with the safe call operator, e.g. `SpUtils.loadEMail()?.isEmpty()?.not()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have problem with nullable reference.

```
 SpUtils.loadEMail()?.isEmpty()
```

This code produces value of type **Boolean?** that's mean expression can return an instance of **Boolean** or **null**.

I suggest following code to solve your problem:

```
return !(SpUtils().loadEMail()?.isEmpty() ?: false);
```

You trying negate **Boolean?** instead of **Boolean**, that [elvis](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) operator returns!

Comment: See the note from @cypressious for the `.not()` option.  Otherwise you have to always consider operator precedence when you construct an expression.

Comment: The [recommended convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#using-nullable-boolean-values-in-conditions) is to compare to the literal boolean:

`SpUtils.loadEMail()?.isEmpty() == false`

Answer (score 3):

`?.` is a [safe call operator](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

In this case it returns you:

- boolean value if the result of `loadEmail()` invocation **is not** `null`
- `null` otherwise

`!` is a [built-in](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#booleans) boolean operation which invokes the `package.Boolean`'s operator called `not()` which works only on non-nullable references. The result of `?.`  is `Boolean?`, thus you get your error.

If you want to negate the whole expression, you can stick to the iRus answer:

```
!(SpUtils().loadEMail()?.isEmpty() ?: false)
```

If you want to negate **just** the `SpUtils().loadEMail()?.isEmpty()` part then the correct variant will be:

```
!(SpUtils().loadEMail()?.isEmpty() ?: true)
```

If the result of `?.` will be null (there is no mail) then the elvis operator will return you `true` (no e-mail) and you'll negate it.

Comment: You don't need the second elvis operator in your last example anymore. The left side is already `Boolean` and not `Boolean?`, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

`!(SpUtils().loadEMail()?.isEmpty() ?: false)` would work, but it's really difficult to see when this would actually return `true`.

It returns `true` when the result of `SpUtils().loadEMail()` is null or not empty. With this knowledge, we can easily make something readable:

`return SpUtils().loadEMail()?.isNotEmpty() ?: true`

You can expand it for even better readability:

```
val email = SpUtils().loadEMail()
if (email == null || email.isNotEmpty()) {
    return true
}
return false
```